# Get instance of current android.intent.category.LAUNCHER activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I have created a library project that I am sharing across several apps.  I implemented a simple session expiration feature that will kick the user back to the login screen after a certain time period.

The login screen activity is my main activity, so in the manifest it looks like this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar"
    android:name="com.blah.application.MyApplication" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.blah.activity.LoginScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

When the session is expired, I want to kick the user back to the login screen, but I don't want to hardcode the name of the activity because it might be different depending on the specific app that is using the library.  Here's what I was doing before:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginScreenActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

This doesn't work if the app's main activity is something different than LoginScreenActivity.  I don't want to hardcode "LoginScreenActivity.class", I want to programmatically determine the name of the main class and then direct the user to that activity...can someone help me out?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I found a way to accomplish the same end result, but it's definitely not great.  Since there is a certain amount of configuration necessary for me to deploy a new app using the same library (strings, bools, etc), I added a string to the strings.xml file for the specific app that defines the "main" activity name for that app:

```
<string name="mainClassName">com.blah.specificapp.activity.SpecificAppLoginScreenActivity</string>
```

Then I can get a handle on that class by name and redirect the user there:

```
Class<?> clazz = null;

try 
{
    clazz = Class.forName(context.getString(R.string.mainClassName));
} 
catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if(clazz != null)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, clazz);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

I know this is a god-awful solution, but it works.  Like I said, there is a certain amount of configuration I have to do for each new app anyway, so adding one more string isn't a huge deal it's just not very elegant.  I'd appreciate any suggestions that can accomplish the same goal without using my hack.

Comment: There can be more than a single _main_ activity per application...

Comment: That's true but if I could get a list of those then I could pick the right one.  The name of the class I'm looking for will always be named "*LoginScreenActivity".

Comment: That sounds just as bad as hadcoding the `class`...

Comment: I agree.  And I CANNOT hardcode the class because I do not know its name.  Maybe I need a completely different approach...any other ideas?

Comment: If you were using the _Navigation_ metadata from _Android 3+_ or the equivalent from the _Support Library_, you could walk up the stack and find out what your root activity is.

Comment: Is there an example of walking the stack up to the root activity that you can provide?  I'm using the support library so that's available to me but I am not finding much help when searching for that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can request a **launch Intent** from the PackageManager, using:

```
Intent launchIntent = PackageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());
```

This will return an Intent that you can use to launch the "main" activity (which I assume is your "login" activity). Just add `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` to this and you should be good to go.

Comment: David - you are a genius.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Just tried it out and it works exactly how I want it to (returns user back to the "main" activity).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can get `PackageManager` from activity context too.
`getApplication().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getApplication().getPackageName())`

Answer (score 0):

How about using a mime-type on your intent filter.

```
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
              android:exported="true" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:label="@string/MT">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <action android:name="com.foo.ACTION_LOGIN" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/x.foo.com.mobile.login" /> 
     </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And launch the activity as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.foo.ACTION_LOGIN");
intent.setType("application/x.foo.com.mobile.login");
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Thus the intent will be serviced by whatever activity is registered with this action/mime-type pair. I am not certain, but I think if that activity is hosted in the same app, it may be chosen first.

Comment: I tried your method and it's throwing an exception:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN typ=application/com.blah.activity.main }

    <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/com.blah.activity.main" />
        </intent-filter>

intent.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");   intent.setType("application/com.blah.activity.main");

Comment: I put together a sample app and saw similar problems.  Altering the intent filter of a launcher activity broke Android's ability to launch the app.  I guess this is a flawed approach.  Sorry to steer you wrong.