# Android app in the background

Tags: android, android-activity, background, android-service

I am developing an application in android studio, and I have to save the location of the device, I did a "locationService" class that extends service, so the location is segmented on my server and the service would be in the background.
I have read the android documentation and there are two types of service (service and linked service), I use the linked service because I need to show the location data in an activity.

The problem is when I close the application, the service dies and does not record the change of location.

How can I prevent the linked service from dying. Thank you

Comment: Please note this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3856940/6759520

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean a "bound" `Service`, not a "linked" `Service`. A bound `Service` will stop running when the last client disconnects from it. To prevent this, you need to call `startService()` and make sure that you return `START_STICKY` from `onStartCommand()` in your `Service`.

You don't need to use a "bound" `Service` in order to pass data from the `Service` to an `Activity`. Another way is to have your `Service` broadcast the data (by adding the data as an "extra" to an `Intent` and calling `sendBroadcast()` with the `Intent`). Your `Activity` can then set up a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen for any data braodcast by your `Service`.

Comment: Thank you.
The correct term is bundle, I already implemented it in my application and it worked correctly, now I want to implement another functionality, when in the background I can launch an activity and display the desired information, but when I minimize the application (press the home and I do not close it), and I send you new information and I want to put my application in the foreground showing that information.

Comment: I assume you mean "bound", not "Bundle". When you want to bring your app to the foreground, just get a "launch Intent" for your app and call `startActivity()` with that. It will bring your app to the foreground so you can do what you want. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14137045/769265

Comment: Thank you.
I have implemented this method and it has worked, now I have another problem, in my service I have a boolean variable that starts with a value of true, and from my application I command it to change to false, but when I close the application, something happens the service as a restart and my variable returns to the initial value (true).
There is some way my service will not "reboot".

Comment: Android can always kill the process hosting your `Service` and restart it. You cannot get around this. You need to come up with another method of dealing with this. You can store something in `SharedPreferences`, or some other persistent storage if necessary.

Comment: Thank you.
I will try to find another solution to solve this, one last question, my application has a button with which I start the service and sends me to another activity, which happens if I press the back button and press the start button again my service ?.
Do you create a new service like a thread?
And if you create a new service how could you control that?

Comment: Services are like singletons in Android. If you call startService() and the service is already running, Android doesn't start another instance. It just calls onStartCommand() on the existing instance

Comment: Thank you.
I have been able to solve all the problems that have arisen during the development of the application.